# Apache NiFi: Processing multiple csv's using the ExecuteScript Processor

Tags: python, csv, apache-nifi, data-cleaning

I have a csv with 70 columns. The 60th column contains a value which decides wether the record is `valid` or `invalid`. If the 60th column has 0, 1, 6 or 7 it's `valid`. If it contains any other value then its `invalid`.

I realised that this functionality wasn't possible relying completely on changing property's of processors in Apache NiFi. Therfore I decided to use the `executeScript processor` and added this python code as the text body.

```py
import csv

valid =0
invalid =0
total =0
file2 = open("invalid.csv","w")
file1 = open("valid.csv","w")

with  open('/Users/himsaragallage/Desktop/redder/Regexo_2019101812750.dat.csv') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f)
    for row in f:
        # print row[1]
        total +=1

        if row[59] == "0" or row[59] == "1" or row[59] == "6" or row[59] == "7":
            valid +=1
            file1.write(row)
        else:
            invalid += 1
            file2.write(row)
file1.close()
file2.close()
print("Total : " + str(total))
print("Valid : " + str(valid))
print("Invalid : " + str(invalid))
```

I have no idea how to use a session and code within the executeScript processor as shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58620599/apache-nifi-how-to-compare-multiple-rows-in-a-csv-and-create-new-column). So I just wrote a simple python code and directed the valid and invalid data to different files. This approach I have used has **many limitations**.

1. I want to be able to dynamically process csv's with different filenames.
2. The csv which the invalid data is sent to, must also have the same filename as the input csv.
3. There would be around 20 csv's in my `redder` folder. All of them must be processed in one go.

Hope you could suggest a method for me to do the following. Feel free to provide me with a solution by editing the python code I have used or even completely using a different set of processors and totally excluding the use of `ExecuteScript Processer`

Comment: You can look into QueryRecord processor instead doing this in Jython script. With that processor, you will be simply able to write a new relationship which says "select * from FLOWFILE where column60 in (0,1,6,7) "

Comment: @Pushkr Can you be clear as to what property/configuration must be changed to "select * from FLOWFILE where column60 in (0,1,6,7) " within the QueryRecord Processer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to route records based on values from one column. There are various ways to make this happen in NiFi. I can think of the following:

- Use [**QueryRecord**](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.QueryRecord/index.html) processor to partition records by column values
- Use [**RouteOnContent**](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.RouteOnContent/) processor to route using a regular expression
- Use [**ExecuteScript**](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-scripting-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript/index.html) processor to create a custom routing logic
- Use [**PartitionRecord**](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.6.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PartitionRecord/index.html) processor to route based on [**RecordPaths**](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/record-path-guide.html)

I show you how to solve your problem using `PartitionRecord` processor. Since you did not provide any example data I created an example use case. I want to distinguish cities in Europe from cities elsewhere. Following data is given:

```
id,city,country
1,Berlin,Germany
2,Paris,France
3,New York,USA
4,Frankfurt,Germany
```

Flow:

[image]

GenerateFlowFile:

[image]

PartitionRecord:

[image]

`CSVReader` should be setup to infer schema and `CSVRecordSetWriter` to inherit schema. `PartitionRecord` will group records by country and pass them on together with an attribute `country` that has the country value. You will see following groups of records:

```
id,city,country
1,Berlin,Germany
4,Frankfurt,Germany

id,city,country
2,Paris,France

id,city,country
3,New York,USA
```

Each group is a flowfile and will have the country attribute, which you will use to route the groups.

RouteOnAttribute:

[image]

All countries from Europe will be routed to the is_europe relationship. Now you can apply the same strategy to your use case.

Answer (score 2):

Here is complete step-by-step instructions on [how to use `QueryRecord` processor](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Running-SQL-on-FlowFiles-using-QueryRecord-Processor-Apache/ta-p/246671)

Basically,  you need to setup highlighted properties

[image]

Comment: This didn't work for me. Did you change any configurations in the `CSVReader` or the `CSVRecordSetWriter`? Also I don't have a header in my csv so I changed the properties within the CSVRecordSetWriter to not take the first line as a header.

Comment: Did you specify csv schema in both reader and writer? What is the error you got?

Comment: It says the header contains a duplicate name. But I have made sure the I have assigned `header` as `fail`

Comment: @HimsaraGallege QueryRecord will not work, if you have no CSV header. Because the column names are used as part of the query, e.g. col60. Do you have any chance to include the header? Else we have to consider another solution.

Comment: @Upvote I included the headers and retried, that's when I am came across the Duplicate name error.

Comment: @HimsaraGallege make sure that you don't have duplicate column names.

Comment: @Upvote yes sure that there aren't any duplicate column headings. Is it possible for you to drop an answer with a test csv. As you have used `Execute Script Processor` for my questions before. Even an answer with `ExecuteScript Processor` is greatly appreciated.

Comment: @HimsaraGallege will do later that day.